# Adding array as child of parent array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am facing difficulty with assigning array in this order:

```
Parent array
-child 1 
-child 2
```

For example, in my code Parent is parent array and ID, Val are children. So if I declare Parent Array size as 5, I want my code to look like this:

```
Parent Size : 5

Parent
-Element 0: 5 
-ID: VP01
-Val: x:0, y:1
,
Parent
-Element 1: 2 
-ID: VP02
-Val: x:1, y:1
,
...
...
```

```
public float[] Parent;
public string ID;
public Vector2 Val;
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: difficult to understant what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a class like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string ID;
    public Vector2 Val;
}
```

you initialize the array:

```
var parent = new Parent[5];
parent[0] = new Parent {ID="VP01", Val = new Vector2(0, 1)};
// and so on to parent[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your needs right, you can do this:

1. Create a separate class/struct, name it e.g. `MyArrayElement`.
2. Inside that class create your fields like e.g. `public float Number`, `public string Id` and `public Vector2 Val` fields.
3. Declare your array as `public MyArrayElement[] myArray`.

Then you can initialize it like this:

```
myArray = new MyArrayElement[]
{
    new MyArrayElement { Number = 1f, Id = "SomeId", Val = new Vector2(1, 5) },
    new MyArrayElement { Number = .5f, Id = "AnotherId", Val = new Vector2(0, 10) },
    // ...more elements here
};
```